# Why can't we override function pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I want to create a member callback variable than can take multiple arguments:

```
class Polygon : public Shape {
    protected:
        void (*onClick)( Polygon * );
        void (*onClick)( Point * );
        void (*onClick)();
    ...
}
```

Of course this code throws an error. Is there any particular reason why I can't or shouldn't do this? And are there alternatives? I don't want three different names for the same behavior.

Comment: Those are member variables, not member functions. Why do you think you should be able to overload something that can't be overloaded?

Comment: Are you attempting to implement three different function pointers, one for each potential function call signature? Or you want a single class member, a pointer that can, somehow, point to functions with different signatures, and, if so, what is your expected behavior if an attempt is made to use the function pointer with a different parameter(s) than the actual function it is pointing to?

Comment: `Of course this code throws an error` And you don't think the error message is relevant to the question?

Comment: You wouldn't get "*three different names for the same callback*" but three different names for three different callbacks.

Comment: Yes they are member variables, that's a typo. I understand the error and it make sense, as per Code-Apprentice's answer, but it seemed intuitive that one can override function pointers just regular functions. I'm trying to implement a single class member for all three potential function calls. It should break.

Comment: How would you assign a value to `mypoly.onClick` ?

Comment: @M.M Theoretically in the same way as you would take a pointer to an overloaded member function - `static_cast`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you'll need to be more specific

Comment: @Pixelchemist
An obvious solution is to make three distinctly named function pointers - onClickPolygon, onClickPoint, etc. - for each type of function callback, I didn't want that because it would be confusing for someone reading the code at a later date.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious
Can you expand on that?

Comment: @M.M
You could use a setter but you would need one for each type of onClick:
setClick( void (*callback)() ), setClick( void (*callback)(Polygon *) )...

This seems like an obvious extension of being able to override functions.

Comment: I think it would be more confusing to have one variable name that is hiding 3 separate variables depending on the context.  It's not a good analogy with overloaded functions because you cannot assign to a function.

Comment: @M.M
" you cannot assign to a function", what do you mean by that?
That's essentially what you are doing when you overload a function, hiding different implementations under one name, I don't know how this is more confusing than that?

Comment: @mand it is just like asking: _I have `int age; double age; string age;` member variables. I want to pass it to different places as age, why can't I name them the same?_

Comment: @mand "assign" means using the assignment operator. You can't do `void f();` and then write something like `f = g;`

Comment: @AdrianShum
Alright, that clarifies things, I made the mistake of thinking that a function pointer's argument list and return type were a part of its name but I guess they are a part of its type instead.

Comment: @M.M I can use something like `auto f = static_cast<void()>(func);` to assign a specific function overload to a variable. The same approach would work (albeit crappily) for what the user is assuming C++ should allow.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious that is initialization, not assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tl;dr: Because the standard doesn't allow you to do it.

Different behaviour using "the same name" is only possible with function overloads (or with templates to some extent) as function pointers do not overload.

You'd have to resort to overloading in order to maintain the same name for `onClick`:

```
 #include <functional>

 class Polygon : public Shape {
 private:
     std::function<void(Polygon*)> _poly_f;
     std::function<void(Point*)> _point_f;
     std::function<void()> _empty_f;
 protected:
    void onClick(Polygon* p) { _poly_f(p); }
    void onClick(Point* p) { _point_f(p); }
    void onClick() { _empty_f(); }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring variables here. Two variable cannot have the same name.

Comment: Yes and that makes sense, but if I were to create these three functions and use each of them as a function pointer the compiler has no problem tracking each of them - why can't we use this functionality also to allow us to override function pointers? I thought function pointers name also included the arguments it takes and its return type. And yes I know the compiler is keeping track of the function's address but that's immaterial.

Comment: @mand a function pointer's **type** includes the argument list.